# I need to create a custom calendar in sharepoint2010 for scheduling Appointments for a Marketing Firm

Tags: development, calendar, guidance

I need to create a custom calendar in sharepoint2010 for scheduling Appointments for a Marketing Firm, but I'm still unexperienced on SharePoint development.

For my requirement be able to add date and time of the appointment, and I also need to include 2 dropdown list to get the sales person and and the Client reference. If possible I would also like to include other info as  the place of appointment, type of appointment and so on.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to start? Should I be able to implement this by using
using visual studio only? or should i use sharepoint designer along with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of that with out of the box functionality. Either by creating a calendar object, or by creating a custom list with a calendar view.

With the custom list you can have the default view be a list and create a standard SharePoint form for the information, then create a calendar view to show elsewhere on the site for users to display the appointment name and time of appointment.

Comment: Thanks hrezs for the suggestion, could you help me with this. I had used a webpart to create a calendar using the         <SharePoint:SPCalendarView ID="cldrAppointments" runat="server">

</SharePoint:SPCalendarView>

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. This might help you. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/list-view-web-part-HA010024052.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As hrezs said, this should be possible with out of the box.

1. Simply add a calendar to your page and select the "Calendar Tools" at the ribbon.
2. Then you select "Create Column" and choose whatever you like (Textbox or dropdown for example).
3. After you created the columns they are available at the form when you create a new item in the calendar.